# Keyboard Commands/Shortcuts in Java on OS X?

Tags: java, macos, shortcut, awtrobot

I would really enjoy if someone could answer this. I've made a robot that clicks every 10 milliseconds ( totally not using this for Idle Mine and Cookie Clicker ;) ).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException{
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    while (true){
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.delay(2);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.delay(10);
    }

}
```

Anyway I have been wondering how to add a keyboard shortcut to quickly toggle the clicker on and off so I don't destroy my computer  trying to close my program. I have searched a lot of places for an answer or a way that works! Please answer.

P.S. - I own a Mac, so I don't know if that changes anything, I think it wouldn't, but it might!

Comment: JNA or JNI could work.

Comment: Completely off topic here, but, if you plan on using it for Cookie Clicker, open the Console (or Press F12 if you're using chrome) and type *Game.cookies = n* where n is some integer number. Also, using Java to accomplish this would be inappropriate. Javascript (with Tampermonkey) would be a better alternative.

Comment: lol yeah I know I could do that but I am experimenting with Java to see what I can do. :)